# Swiftui invisible bar on the top of the screen

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar

I have the following in problem.
If I try to give a view a color (Color.red for example)
I get the following output:
[image: Big white bar above red color]

I can just add .edgesignoressafearea(.top) and the top also gets red. But when I want to add an clickable item, the user won't be able to click it since there still is this invisible bar on the top of the screen. Does Anyone know what my problem is? The problem is in all the tabable views(Timeline, Favorits, Discover, Account). So It must be in either the first code or in tabview (second code) that I send in this post.

When the user clicks on the app first they get this view sending the user to the signin view or the app itself:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: tabView().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $tabview, label: { EmptyView() })
            NavigationLink(destination: loginView().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $login, label: { EmptyView() })
                
            if tabview == false && login == false {
                Text("loading")
                    .onAppear(perform: checklogin)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Then the apps sends them to tabview:

```
 var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        Timeline()
            .tabItem {
                Label("timeline", systemImage: "house")
            }
            .tag(0)
        
        Favorits()
            .tabItem {
                Label("favorits", systemImage: "heart")
            }
            .tag(1)
        
        Discover()
            .tabItem {
                Label("discover", systemImage: "network")
            }
            .tag(2)
        
        Account()
            .tabItem {
                Label("account", systemImage: "person")
            }
            .tag(3)
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
 }
```

The problem happens on all of this views.
This is the view where I made the screenshot of:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
        Text("Hello fav!")
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add **.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)** and remove your navigation bar if you don't want to be able to get back to your login view anytime.
That's the full code with a login page, now it depends what you want on that login page :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var showLoginView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showLoginView {
                MainView()
            } else {
                Button("Login") {
                    self.showLoginView = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            TimeLine()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("timeline", systemImage: "house")
                }
            Favorits()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("favorits", systemImage: "heart")
                }
            Discover()
                 .tabItem {
                     Label("discover", systemImage: "network")
              }
            Account()
                 .tabItem {
                     Label("account", systemImage: "person")
              }
        }
        
    }
    
}
    
struct TimeLine: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}

struct Favorits: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            Text("Hello fav!")
        }
    }
}

struct Discover: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
struct Account: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.purple
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @chrispsv tell me if it solves your issue

Comment: It does make the entire screen red. But the space that was white (but now red) still is there. So if for example I would instead of the text do a VStack {Text(" hello fav!") Spacer() the text will disappear}

Comment: Yes because in the views that I need to make there will be buttons in the top. Those buttons won't be clickable because that white thing is a weird type of overlay. I have deleted all the .navigationTitle("") but the whitespace is still there.

Comment: I try to have a better understanding of what you want to do, because the code I gave is just to have a full red screen with "hello fav" in the middle. But you want to have a Tab bar and a navigation bar? because the space you have is probably your nav bar

Comment: No the red color is just to show that there is a big white invisible thing on the top of all of my tabbar views. I want to build a view with a button somewhere in the top. But that will be impossible because of the big invisible thing. with .edgesignoresafearea(.top) I can make my view how I want it. The problem with that is that the view will draw under the invisible topbar therefore every button or tap-able thing won't work since the user will tap on the big invisible topbar instead of the button itself. So I try to figure out why there is a big invisible topbar and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: I think that white area is there because you added a navigation view, Comment every line and braced that has navigation written in it and see if it removes it?

Comment: Yes the problem with that is that I need navigationview in order for the app to work. So if i comment all of it out then the app won't even display the tabbar view. If I comment every line it will disappear so it has something to do with the navigationview

Comment: Ok so the reason you keep the navigation view here is to keep ur tabbar t on the bottom of the view. I that correct?

Comment: No when a user clicks on the app they start on the first code (ContentView) there the code will check if a user is logged in or not. If a user is logged-in they will be sent to loginView. Otherwise to Tapview (second piece of code). I need navigation view for that. Also later on I need navigation view to send users to different views. The button that I want to build on the top of the screen wil also link to another view. I need navigation view for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239370/discussion-between-abv-and-chrispsv).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the navigation Title to "" because your View is embedded in NavigationView

Create a ViewModifier like this and apply it to your VStack

```
struct HiddenNavBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I have put this viewmodifier on all my views. ContentView -> Tabview -> the Z-stack. But it doesn't change the look. The whitebar is still there

Comment: This does not help.